# Ubuntu 14.04lts server powers off automatically

Tags: 14.04, server, shutdown, raid

I have a ubuntu 14.04lts 12G RAM and 1TB HD server. Whenever there is a lot of operation going on like upload and download simultaneously the system all of a sudden powers off. I am also told that this happens because the system is not RAID configured. I don't know whats the exact reason. Can somebody shed some light on this behavior..?